# discord.py I can't run server-info command

Tags: discord.py

I recently program with discord.py and after several searches I still can't find a way to implement this command (it also leads me to have problems with other commands that request information from the server) and therefore I need help if you can.
In this case I want to create a command that gives me the server information.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\PC GIUSEPPE\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'server' is not defined
```

Code:

```
@client.command(aliases=["serverinfo","Server_info","Serverinfo","SERVERINFO","si","Si","SI"])
@commands.has_any_role('Moderatori', 'Triumvirato', 'Co-Triumvirato', 'Senatori', '690956686147453048')
async def ServerInfo(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.name
    name_server = server.name
    create_server = server.create
    owner_server = server.owner.name
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Informazioni del server",
        description=f'Tutte le informazioni generali del nostro server {name_server}',
        color=0x003399
    )
    embed.set_thumbnail(url='')
    embed.set_footer(text=f'Richiesto da: {author}')
    embed.add_field(
        name='Server creato il:',
        value='f{create_server}',
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Owner Attuale del server:',
        value='f{create_server}',
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Server creato il:',
        value=f'{create_server}',
    )
    embed.add_field(
        name='Server creato il:',
        value=f'{owner_server}',
    )
```

Comment: where is ```server``` defined in your code?

Comment: I never defined it ... how could I do it?

Comment: somewhat depends on where you get ```server``` from.  I'm guessing this variable is a global one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't defined `server` in your code, that's why you have this error.
`Server` was the old discord.py reference for the discord server the bot is in. Now, you'll have to use [`Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild#discord.Guild) like so:

```py
@client.command()
async def ServerInfo(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.name
    guild = ctx.guild
    name = guild.name
    create_server = server.created_at
    owner_server = server.owner.name
    (...)
```

You could also create a dictionnary of those informations:

```py
@client.command()
async def ServerInfo(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.name
    guild = ctx.guild
    infos = {
        'name': guild.name
        'owner': guild.owner.name
        'created_at': guild.created_at
    }
    (...)
```

In case you don't really know the difference between discord.py (before v1.0) and discord.py@rewrite (after v1.0), here's a [summary link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html?highlight=migration).